# How can you unpack a Color.PackedValue

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying save a Color to a database.  I know I could cut the color into 4 parts, RGBA but it seems silly to save a color using 3 columns.  So then I though of simply saving it to a string using a limiter, or even just using 3 characters per color.  But again it seems silly.  The Color structure has an packedValue Property, which seems to do something with the values to create a uint.  but I don't know how to unpack it.  Anyone have any ideas

```
Color c = new Color.Black;
uint i = c.PackedValue;
Color newColor=Color.FromUINT(i); // This doesn't work of course
```

Comment: The properites A, B, G, and R (of Color) return the four compnents as byte values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PackedValue` is a read/write property.  You don't need to do any bit shifting to make use of it.

```
var c = new Color() { PackedValue = packedColor };
Console.WriteLine(c.A);
Console.WriteLine(c.R);
Console.WriteLine(c.G);
Console.WriteLine(c.B);
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the first Google result](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3i7u-EljaYsJ%3adream-forever.net/Blog/2009/08/26/unpacking-a-color-from-the-color-packed-property/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us):

```
//First lets pack the color
Color color = new Color(155, 72, 98, 255);
uint packedColor = color.PackedValue;
//Now unpack it to get the original value.
Color unpackedColor = new Color();
unpackedColor.B = (byte)(packedColor);
unpackedColor.G = (byte)(packedColor >> 8);
unpackedColor.R = (byte)(packedColor >> 16);
unpackedColor.A = (byte)(packedColor >> 24);
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to be rude!  Just provide a reference for my answer.  I can see how it came off that way, sorry!

Comment: This answer did not work quite properly.  likely due to the byte shifting I dunno.  Not saying it wont work, but the answer by Cole Campbell works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the B and R channels when doing the bit shifting. IIRC DirectX uses BGRA color while XNA uses RGBA. So if we modify the sample code above to read

```
//First lets pack the color
Color color = new Color(155, 72, 98, 255);
uint packedColor = color.PackedValue;
//Now unpack it to get the original value.
Color unpackedColor = new Color();
unpackedColor.R = (byte)(packedColor);
unpackedColor.G = (byte)(packedColor >> 8);
unpackedColor.B = (byte)(packedColor >> 16);
unpackedColor.A = (byte)(packedColor >> 24);
```

you will get the correct color value back out of it